# How to rewrite specific for loop to make it work faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops

I have written this code using for loop to compare values between two lists:

```
list1 = [3,4,5,6,7,8] 
list2 = [8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20]

list3 = []
list4 = []

for i in list1:
  for j in list2:
    if (i + j)%2 == 0:
      list3.append(j)
      list4.append(i)
```

it adds values from list1 and list2 to list4 and list3 accordingly if sum of values from list1 and list2 are even

The output is:

```
list3: 
[9,
 8,
 10,
 12,
 14,
 16,
 18,
 20,
 9,
 8,
 10,
 12,
 14,
 16,
 18,
 20,
 9,
 8,
 10,
 12,
 14,
 16,
 18,
 20]

list4: [3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

But when list1 and list2 are much larger (thousands values in each), it gets really slow. How could I rewrite this loop to make it faster? Is it possible to do it using map?

P.S.

I am interested in finding out how to make loop faster, cause i want to use similar concept to other conditions (not only (i + j)%2 == 0). for example comparing two texts from two lists and measuring cosine similarity between their embeddings

Comment: @buran its just example. I'm more interested in finding out how to make loop faster, cause i want to use similar concept to other conditions (not only i%2 == 0). for example comparing two texts from two lists and measuring cosine similarity between their embeddings

Comment: So, basically this is XY problem right now...

Comment: What do you mean by making loop faster ? Do you want to change how loop work internally

Comment: You can't make it faster if you *have* to perform an operation between every value in one list and every value in the other list, it will always be `O(n^2)`. The only way to speed it up is to take advantage of optimisations such as @buran suggested.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi yes, for example ```list(map(lambda x: x * x, [1,2,3,4,5]))``` is faster than 
```lst = []  for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:  lst.append(i*i)
```

Comment: @Nick isn't using map faster? isn't using parallel computing faster?

Comment: @gh1222 Consider using e.g. [cython](https://cython.org/).

Comment: @gh1222 sure, if you can parallelise and multi-thread, it will be faster than not doing so, and likewise there may be optimisations by using compiled code (such as your `map` example), but you still have an `O(n^2)` problem - it's just the multiplier may get smaller.  But that sort of optimisation is probably specific to each problem you have.

Comment: Note that a list comprehension is faster than your `map` example i.e. `[x*x for x in [1,2,3,4,5]]`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make the loop faster without changing your approach/algorithm. Nested loops in your case result in an O(n*m) algorithm (n - size of list1, m - size of list 2). To reduce time complexity, you need to come up with a different algorithm

[You can try modifying geeksforgeeks' solution to a similar problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-in-array-whose-sum-is-divisible-by-k/)

[If you want to know more about time complexity, read this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)

Comment: so that is the question. im asking for suggestion about faster algorithm...

Comment: There was an answer before that got downvoted, which basically suggested using another algorithm. I've already given you a link to a similar problem, where the solution can be modified to fit your needs. And no, you're not asking about algorithm - you specifically asked about rewriting the for loop to make it more efficient. My answer - you cannot rewrite this for loop to make it more efficient with this algorithm.